# activity diagram in uml regarding parallel activities

Tags: android, uml, activity-diagram

I had a doubt regarding parallel activities that occur in the system. How can we represent those in the diagram? Is there always a need of fork or the decision element can also be used?
Eg.: The user can choose among "Add Book" , "Search Book", "Search User" and "Update profile". So after the user logs in the system he can choose among the above operations.[image: activity diagram]
Below is the image of my activity diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-reference.html the

> ..**Fork node** is a control node that has one incoming edge and multiple outgoing edges and is used to split incoming flow into multiple **concurrent** flows..

and

> ..**Decision node** is a control node that accepts tokens on one or two incoming edges and selects one outgoing edge from **one or more outgoing** flows..

In your case the 1 user will select and perform 1 of the possible actions and do it 1 at a time. The user will not use 2 or more mice or 2 or more browser tabs to use the application concurrently..

Comment: yes, the user will choose one operation for eg. Search book at a time when he logs in. So there will be one operation occurring at a time. Is the fork node correct? @xmojmr

Comment: @jueleemahant fork is for concurrent flows. in your case the flow will not be concurrent. So in my opinion the final answer is: use decision node

Comment: Thank you @xmojmr i"ll perform the necessary changes

Comment: @juelee if you find my answer useful then you can use the **vote on** part of the http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. If you're interested in an examples of activity diagrams using fork/decision nodes then definitely take a look at http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-examples.html

Comment: @juelee I did not mean by my last comment as that you should take-away the accepted flag from BobRodes's answer, I just meant that the well-established way to say "thanks" here at Stack Overflow is using the voting button. Anyway, welcome to Stack Overflow and spend some time by browsing the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and also reading some Meta Stack Overflow articles with high number of views at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=month can give you an idea of what kind of community did you join and what can you expect from it and what does it expect from you :)

Answer (score 2):

I'll expand a bit on xmojmr's answer.  As xmojmr says, forks and joins are for simultaneous and separate activities that have to be done before you can continue with something else.

Your diagram is saying that in order to do a Select Operation, you have to do an Add Book, a Search Book, a Search User Profile and a View Profile.  You have to do all four of them, every time, and when all four of them are completed, you do a Do You Want to Continue.  Also, Adding a Book requires that you  add a book, delete a book, and view a book list, all three.

This is obviously not correct.  In both cases, you're choosing from one of a group of possiblities.  So, you're looking for a decision as xmojmr also says.

Now, an example of when you would use forks and joins would be in performing a background check.  You would check a number of sources, for example a fingerprint database, a DMV check, Photo matching database, and criminal records database.  You'd have to check all of these before you had a complete background check.  However, none of the four are dependent on the others, and each one can run concurrently with the others.  This is the sort of scenario that uses forks and joins.