# activity diagram for quick books exchange

Tags: android-activity, uml

I need help to improve the activity diagram attached below. The diagram is regarding a book exchange app. [image: activity-books exchange] please tell the required modifications.

Comment: How is this question different from your another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26681136/activity-diagram-in-uml-regarding-parallel-activities ?

Comment: I know its not much different but can you please suggest any corrections or modifications needed in the above diagram @xmojmr

Comment: So the diagram is the same but your question is different?